# mysql server won't start MAMP

Tags: mysql, mamp

I've read a few answers on here that say when your mysql server won't start in MAMP you should run

```
sudo killall -9 mysqld
```

I've used that in the past and it has worked but for whatever reason it is not working this time. I'm getting this error message in the logs:

```
[04-May-2014 11:02:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /Users/Chappell/Websites/LFB/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1372
```

I recently transferred the files (not MAMP itself) for the site I'm working on from another computer where I was developing locally. Not sure if that's relevant but thought I'd point it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was quite simple in the end. I was using different versions of MAMP on the two separate computers. I just installed the latest version and it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 13):

I first tried 'sudo killall -9 mysqld' and didn't find any processes.

What did work for me was removing all files (but not directories) in the mysql dir:
rm /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/*

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the log files within the MAMP directory fixed this for me. 
Quit MAMP and try this in the terminal.

```
rm /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/ib_logfile0

rm /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/ib_logfile1
```

Open MAMP back up and try starting the servers again.

Comment: This solution not worked for me. Thanks dear.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions fixed my issue.

What I did was backup databases from `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db`, and also backup "MAMP" folder.

Then deleted all and reinstalled Mamp.

Apparently my databases in `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db` were damaged because when I copied the old ones there , the same issue started to happen.

I ended up copying (inside `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56`) only the important database folder, and ibdata1 file. Now everything works fine.

Comment: This solution not worked for me. Thanks dear.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question but here's what worked for me:

I had mysql workbench boothing at computer restart.
Deleted the software and everything was working.