# How can I resolve MySQL not starting in MAMP without deleting and reinstalling?

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to get MySQL running on MAMP. Other documentation on this site is suggesting to delete it all and reinstall MAMP again. I was in the middle of a WordPress theme development project and had already built the database for it, so this is not an option for me.

This is the error log:

```
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
170225 17:42:34 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

I have no clue what this is telling me. There are no current MySQL processes running, at least that is what I gathered from this:

```
danales-MacBook-Pro:~ danale$ killall -9 mysqld
No matching processes belonging to you were found
```

I am using a MacBook Pro Sierra.

Comment: @ArsalanMithani, your suggestion lead me to this documentation:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455841/mysql-server-wont-start-mamp/28654878#28654878. So go ahead and post it as an answer, although I would like to know why it is that removing those files worked.

Comment: Added, i cannot see my comment??? i was deleting somewhere else i think i deleted at the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all files (but not directories) in the mysql dir: `rm /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/`

Files may be causing the issue, i suggest copy them somewhere before doing this.