# PHPMyAdmin does not recognize my databases

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp, macos-sierra

So here's the details on what has happened and what I've done:

1. For some unknown reason, mysql did not start on my MAMP. I tried reinstalling MAMP and this command based on a web search:

   `killall -9 mysqld`

but it didn't work for me.

2. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021564/mamp-mysql-server-wont-start-no-mysql-processes-are-running) post on stackoverflow, I deleted some
   files and it made mysql run again in MAMP:
   [image]
3. I could go to PHPMyAdmin again and it did list my databases:
   [image]
4. However, when I clicked on each of them, it gave me an error mentioning that

> No tables found in database

[image]

5. And when I clicked on each table, it gave the error that:

> No partitioning defined.

[image]

6. Then again I searched the web and came across this command to fix the issue:

   `chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql/`

But it gives me this error:

> chown: mysql.mysql: illegal user name

Any suggestions or solutions? The databases belong to Wordpress websites.

Comment: what is the username?

Comment: @WEBjuju You mean, I should try the username on my system instead of mysql.mysql?? like: chown -R USERNAME.USERNAME /var/lib/mysql/

Comment: have a look on [this](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=762045) or [here](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/43934/#post-244362)

Comment: @Blueblazer172 I get errors like: -bash: groupadd: command not found
and similar ones

Comment: @WEBjuju it gives erros: `chown: mysql: No such file or directory`
`chown: /var/lib/mysql/: No such file or directory`

Comment: i guess you are logged in as user `mysql`

Comment: according to your screenshot of where your mysql56 folder is, your command should be `chown -R mysql:mysql /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56`

Comment: please note the command parameter for `user:group` is colon separated.

Comment: @WEBjuju how do I know what the username and group is exactly? as Admin a group?

Comment: What does the MySQL log say when trying to start? What did it say before you deleted those files?

Comment: In most cases, the ibdata1 file contains information essential to the proper operation of your database. While the problem certain could be bad permissions as suggested in the comments, it seems very likely that when you removed the ibdata1, ib_logfile0, and ib_logfile1 files you basically corrupted your database.