# MAMP 4.2 MySQL Server Not Starting

Tags: mamp

I recently upgraded from MAMP 4.1.1 to MAMP 4.2 on my Mac running MacOS 10.12.6. After upgrading, MAMP 4.2 will not start the MySQL server. Additionally, there is not an option to Stop servers. I see a green box to the right of Apache Server along with the the ability to select Preferences and Start Servers. Open WebStart page is grayed out.

I followed the instructions on [MAMP mysql server won't start. No mysql processes are running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021564/mamp-mysql-server-wont-start-no-mysql-processes-are-running) to delete the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files from MAMP/db/mysql56, but that did not work. In addition to the ib_logfiles, I also deleted ibdata1 followed by all of the contents of mysql56, but neither of those worked.

Lastly, I do not see a mysqld running in Activity Monitor.

Any help in restoring my MAMP functionality is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and tried the same things which didn't solved it.

What solved it for me is I tried starting mySQL in terminal manually in Terminal, here:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh
```

I saw this error in Terminal prompt:

```
mysqld_safe error: log-error set to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err', however file don't exists. Create writable for user 'mysql'.
```

So I manually create a file '**/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err**' and retry **startMysql.sh**, mySQL then started with no problem.

Back to MAMP app console, I can also start/stop servers and 'Open WebStart Page' with no problem now.