# How to recover mysql databases with errors of table, Table 'xyz.forum_posts' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

When deleting the files in .../db/ for the MAMP program in mac, I am now not able to get my databases to show up although the folders are there. Should I reinstall MAMP or how can I convert the folders to SQL files?

When opening up the MAMP phpmyadmin I get an error across the top for the tables, saying

SOME ERRORS HAVE BEEN DETETECTED IN THIS SERVER. PLEASE CHECK BELOW.

Notice in ./templates/table/structure/display_table_stats.phtml#4
Undefined index: TABLE_COMMENT

Backtrace

./libraries/Template.php#152: include(./templates/table/structure/display_table_stats.phtml)
./libraries/controllers/table/TableStructureController.php#1379: PMA\libraries\Template->render(array)
./libraries/controllers/table/TableStructureController.php#1255: PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->getTableStats()
./libraries/controllers/table/TableStructureController.php#355: PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->displayStructure(
array,
array,
array,
boolean false,
array,
array,
)
./tbl_structure.php#47: PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->indexAction()

Comment: why did you delete your database files? And why did you expect your database to still function properly after you deleted its files? If you have a backup, use it.

Comment: Yes, file management is open source, and I did it because I blindly followed directions about restarting MYSQL on MAMP: "What worked for me was removing all files (but not directories) in the mysql dir." Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021564/mamp-mysql-server-wont-start-no-mysql-processes-are-running

And it seems I deleted the files in the mysql56 dir(one directory up)

Comment: Well if you deleted something by accident and you haven't got a backup, then that's pretty much the end of the affair, unless it's in the trash can on your O/S. Whether the files happen to be part of some database engine software is kind of irrelevant to that fact.

Comment: FOund it in the trash!