# MySQL does not start with MAMP Pro (5.0.1)

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

This is my error log, I cant figure out why mysql wont start with MAMP pro. It starts with MAMP.

`2018-08-15T20:00:17.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.461794Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.462033Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.21) starting as process 80443 ...`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.466069Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ is case insensitive`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.468580Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.468648Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-08-15T20:07:13.468705Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.468724Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.468779Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB`
`2018-08-15T20:07:13.469152Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1`
`2018-08-15T20:07:13.469343Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions`
`2018-08-15T20:07:13.470836Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M`
`2018-08-15T20:07:13.484818Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool`
`2018-08-15T20:07:13.498079Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The Auto-extending innodb_system data file './ibdata1' is of a different size 0 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file: initial 768 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.498170Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.807668Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.807745Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.807819Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.807888Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.807956Z 0 [Note] Binlog end`
`2018-08-15T20:07:13.808103Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'`
`2018-08-15T20:07:13.808957Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete`

`2018-08-15T20:07:13.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended`

I have no mysql instances running. Any help here will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Two points. First, this is better posted on the MAMP support forum, because it mostly looks like a MAMP bug, not an error on your part. Second, don't use MAMP, it's convoluted, arcane, and frequently causes issues like this only for the convenience of having a gui with a clickable button to start/stop. Try using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to build/start/stop/update a local dev environment. Aside from about an hour of learning it's commands, you will be much happier with the flexibility of the result, and it's a lot more stable and understandable.

Comment: The reason that MAMP is such a collossal pain to fix, is because they replace ALL of the config options with their own internal environment variables, which are not explained, debuggable, or otherwise understandable in any coherent way outside the very limited subset of options you get in the gui. Even if a log gives you something relevant, good luck tracking down how to actually change it in MAMP-speak.

Comment: @mopsyd The thing is I need to update my laravel project from 5.5 to 5.6, for that, I have to update PHP from 7.0 to 7.1 or higher. I don't want my other projects to get affected because of this. so was searching for an easy quick solution. Did u mean homestead or homebrew? I did think of doing it with homestead, but someone suggested me I use MAMP as its easier and hassle-free. Instead, I'm in a loop just trying to figure out how to get MAMP pro to work with my project. So homestead will be a better option than MAMP pro right?? Thank you for replying.

Comment: update: I followed some stack overflow solutions, but nothing worked for me.
tried deleting the log files 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021564/mamp-mysql-server-wont-start-no-mysql-processes-are-running

Also checked if any mysql instances are running and stopped them

Comment: If you need to run multiple project-specific php instances from localhost, your best option is probably docker, which can run them concurrently. Homebrew can only run one at a time, but you can unlink and relink them as needed. MAMP can switch between its included versions, but only the versions that ship with it.

Comment: Your likely fastest answer is to backup your existing databases and reinstall MAMP entirely. I have at many points put days into trying to fix MAMP issues like this in the past, and eventually found the best answer was not using it, because when it breaks, there is usually no clear answer on how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with my filesystem. That's why MAMP PRO did not work. A friend helped me set up my laptop at the beginning and we chose the Apple File System (APFS) which is case-insensitive. Then I created a partition of the disk and formatted it to have Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled). That's when everything worked.