# Recovering data from old MySQL Database into a new one Mac OSX

Tags: mysql, sql, database, macos

I have a full data folder which includes all of my previous databases from my old instance of MySQL. I upgraded OSX 10.6 to 10.7, I started having problems almost instantly so reinstalled mysql and phpMyAdmin (PMA).

I have tried simply moving the `data/` folder to `usr/local/mysql/data/` but then MySQL will not start at all.

So I tried moving just the database folder into `data/` - This works, I see my database in PMA, however when i click it, theres no tables.

If I move all the files inside the database folder into a new one created - I see all the tables but get this error : [image: Error]

So can anyone tell me, where or what i am doing wrong?

Comment: See if this link helps   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443428/cant-find-file-ci-users-frm-errno-13

Answer (score 0):

This was a permissions problem.

Downloading an app such as [BatChmod](http://www.lagentesoft.com/batchmod/) helped me.

Or follow this link : [Can't find file: './ci/users.frm' (errno: 13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443428/cant-find-file-ci-users-frm-errno-13)

MySQL needs its permissions.