# different results of mysql in python and mysql console

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I want to show the createtable time of `mysql` table:

I run this in `mysql` console

```
MariaDB [Restaurant]> select CREATE_TIME from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'mytalbe';
```

`+---------------------+
| CREATE_TIME         |
+---------------------+
| 2016-06-02 15:38:02 |
| NULL                |
+---------------------+`

But I run this sentence under python, it goes wrong:

```
sql='select CREATE_TIME from information_schema.tables where table_name = %s;'
value=('mytalbe',)
result=cur.execute(sql,value)
```

It throws an exception as:

> Warning: Can't find file:'./performance_schema/mytalbe.frm'(errno:13)
>   result=cur.execute(sql,value)

What should I do to get the right result as in mysql?
Thanks very much!

Comment: its permission error see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443428/cant-find-file-ci-users-frm-errno-13).

Comment: but I do not have the root permission of the server. I can not read the performance_schema file using my account, what should I do?

Comment: But in mysql the sentence runs successful. why this happen?

Comment: try a simple query like `select * from tablename ` check if results are coming.

Comment: 'select * from tablename', this sentence runs successful both in python and mysql

Comment: why don't you specify the table name in query itself instead of using value.

Comment: since I want to separate variable from sql sentence. And this sentence is wrong in mysql :select CREATE_TIME from information_schema.tables where table_name = mytalbe;

Comment: Do `select USER()` when you are logged into console and via python. Permissions can depend on both username and hostname.

Comment: Yes!! select user() works. Could you tell me why this works?